# body not respecting the law of reflection at lower speeds

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, matter.js

I am trying to simulate a ball bouncing around a pool table and have encountered a of problem. (The view is looking down on the table from above).

I always want the ball to bounce off the boundaries according to The Law of Reflection. `Angle of incidence = angle of reflection`

[image]

At the end of the simulation on the right boundary, the ball appears to roll along it. Why doesn't it follow the law of reflection?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5sjx7oyw/

```
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Vector = Matter.Vector,
    Events = Matter.Events;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

engine.world.gravity.y = 0; // gravity not needed in this app

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    canvas: canvas,
    engine: engine,
    options: {wireframes: true}
});

var ball_options = {
    density: 0.04,
  restitution: 1,// 0 = no bouncing, 1 = 100% of kinetic energy bounce back
  friction: 0,
  frictionAir: 0.05,
  inertia: Infinity
};

var boundary_options = {
  isStatic: true
};

var ball = Bodies.circle(100, 150, 11, ball_options);

var boundary_left = Bodies.rectangle(10, 160, 100, 200, boundary_options);
var boundary_right = Bodies.rectangle(300, 160, 100, 200, boundary_options);
var boundary_top = Bodies.rectangle(150, 10, 200, 100, boundary_options);
var boundary_bottom = Bodies.rectangle(150, 300, 200, 100, boundary_options);

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [
    boundary_left,
  boundary_right,
  boundary_top,
  boundary_bottom,
  ball
  ]);

render.options.height = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
Engine.run(engine);
Render.run(render);

Body.applyForce(ball, { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0.2, y: 0.5 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with the help of the creator of the library.

https://jsfiddle.net/8exLLLv6/55/

Adding the following to my code fixed the issue:

```
Matter.Resolver._restingThresh = 0.1;
```

See the [gibhub](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/394#issuecomment-289913662) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in computer is not real numbers; they are inteters.
The 'float' means 'number like float'.
That's why velocity in x-axis does not reduce to 0 continuously.
In the code, initial velocity in x-axis is less than one in y-axis.
So the 'Discrete effect' appears in x-axis.
You can feel like real ball when restitution is almost to 1.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I have changed the `restitution` to 1 however I am still getting the effect of it rolling down the boundary? Could you give me an example?

Comment: I suggest frictionAir: 0.00.

Comment: Yes this does give me perfect reflection, however I do want the ball to eventually stop.